# Centos 8 - Can't parse HTML files as PHP without a file download occuring

Tags: php, apache-2.4, centos8

I'm migrating a site from a Centos 7 server to a Centos 8 server.

The site has PHP code in files with a HTML extension, usually I use this in a htaccess file:

```
RemoveHandler .html .htm

AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .htm .html
AddType application/x-httpd-php .htm .html
```

But this is causing a download of the file.

PHP is working and I can run a .php file with no problems. I can also run a HTML file when this is turned off.

I have set `security.limit_extensions = .php .html` in `/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf` and tried a multitude of different methods in the htaccess files but no difference is made.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is:

```
<FilesMatch \.(php|phar|html)$>
    SetHandler "proxy:unix:/run/php-fpm/www.sock|fcgi://localhost"
</FilesMatch>
```